# Alternative of file_exists function for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have uploaded images into a directory inside my theme folder and trying to use file_exists to output the images.

Not all my posts have images so that is why I'm using the file_exists function.

I am not getting the desired results and would love some insight on this issue.

```
    $preGetImage = get_template_directory_uri();                                                                                
    $vendorPhotoLogo = $preGetImage."/img/vendorimages/logo-".$vendor->acctno.".png";
    $vendorPhotoImg = $preGetImage."/img/vendorimages/img-".$vendor->acctno.".png";

    if(file_exists($vendorPhotoImg)){
      echo '<img src="'.$vendorPhotoImg.'"/>';
    }

    if(file_exists($vendorPhotoLogo)){
      echo '<img src="'.$vendorPhotoLogo.'"/>';
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what inputs are triggering what results? Are you seeing image tags for all, image tags for none, etc.

Comment: Try using `get_template_directory()` rather than `get_template_directory_uri()`

Comment: To add to what @Dre is saying - you cannot rely on checking if a file exists using the URI, you need to use the file path - which is what `get_template_directory()` will get for you.

Comment: And along the same lines, you do want the URI when echo'ing the image tag but not when checking if `file_exists`. So you would want to check if the `file_exists` under `get_template_directory()` but echo it under `get_template_directory_uri()`. `file_exists` looks at the file system, not the URI but the image tag looks under the URI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me explain to help you out:

[`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) runs on the server side to see if a file exists on the server's hard disk. Since it runs on the server side, you need to check it via an absolute path to the folder where the file exists.

Stay with me....

When you run `if(file_exists($vendorPhotoImg))`, PHP checks if the specified file exists on the server's hard drive.  If yes, then it runs the code within the code block, i.e. the `img` HTML is rendered out to the browser.

For checking if the file exists, you have to use the absolute path to the server's hard drive location.  You use [`get_template_directory()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory) to get the folder path for your theme.

But wait, you need the URL path to the image location for the front-end. To get the absolute path to the image's URI, [`get_template_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/).

Here's the code you need:

```
$theme_directory = get_template_directory();
$theme_uri       = get_template_directory_uri();

$vendorPhotoLogo = '/img/vendorimages/logo-' . $vendor->acctno . '.png';
$vendorPhotoImg  = '/img/vendorimages/img-' . $vendor->acctno . '.png';


if ( file_exists( $theme_directory . $vendorPhotoImg ) ) {
    printf( '<img src="%s"/>', esc_url( $theme_uri . $vendorPhotoImg ) );
}

if ( file_exists( $theme_directory . $vendorPhotoImg ) ) {
    printf( '<img src="%s"/>', esc_url( $theme_uri . $vendorPhotoLogo ) );
}
```

Notice how the `file_exists()` uses the theme directory and the `img` source uses the URI.

A couple of notes for you:

1. The code uses `esc_url()` to sanitize the URL before sending it out to the browser.
2. I prefer `printf()` over echo and concatenating strings in this edge case.  You can use what you want here.

Comment: Awesome this worked. Thank you for the detailed explanation. : )